# Vector image in TypedArray Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using custom `View`s in my application,

I have declared attributes like this

```
<declare-styleable name="MySelectView">
    <attr name="selected" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="iconSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="imageSelected" format="reference" />
    <attr name="imageUnSelected" format="reference" />
    <attr name="vectorImageSelected" format="reference" />
    <attr name="vectorImageUnSelected" format="reference" />
    <attr name="setOnClickListener" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

In my `View` I am getting the attribute values as below.

```
 private void applyAttributeSet(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs == null) {
            return;
        }
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.MySelectView,
                0, 0);

        try {
            selected = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MySelectView_selected, false);
            size = a.getDimension(R.styleable.MySelectView_iconSize, Util.dpToPx(size));

            selectedDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MySelectView_imageSelected);
            unSelectedDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MySelectView_imageUnSelected);


            setOnClickListener = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MySelectView_setOnClickListener, true);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }




    <com.mathrusoft.infogo.widget.MySelectView
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/news_item_bottom_view_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/news_item_bottom_view_size"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:iconSize="@dimen/news_item_bottom_view_size"
        app:imageSelected="@drawable/ic_star_24dp"
        app:imageUnSelected="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_24dp"
        app:setOnClickListener="false" />
```

it works fine if I am sending normal drawable in `app:imageSelected` or `app:imageUnSelected` if I send the vector image, I am getting error in inflate `Exception` at `selectedDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MySelectView_imageSelected);`

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class com.mathrusoft.infogo.widget.MySelectView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.adapter.AdapterNewsList.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterNewsList.java:36)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.adapter.AdapterNewsList.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterNewsList.java:27)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2007)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1764)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1020)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5762)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:771)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:757)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.adapter.AdapterNewsList.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterNewsList.java:36)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.adapter.AdapterNewsList.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterNewsList.java:27)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2007)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1764)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1020)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5762)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:771)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:757)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_star_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200c8
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2156)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2075)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.widget.MySelectView.applyAttributeSet(MySelectView.java:65)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.widget.MySelectView.<init>(MySelectView.java:41)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.adapter.AdapterNewsList.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterNewsList.java:36)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.adapter.AdapterNewsList.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterNewsList.java:27)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2007)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1764)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1020)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5762)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:771)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:757)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2152)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2075)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.widget.MySelectView.applyAttributeSet(MySelectView.java:65)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.widget.MySelectView.<init>(MySelectView.java:41)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.adapter.AdapterNewsList.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterNewsList.java:36)
       at com.mathrusoft.infogo.adapter.AdapterNewsList.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterNewsList.java:27)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15092)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4645)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
```

Comment: are you using `VectorDrawableCompat`?